# The representative matrix of an polynomial transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking at a linear transformation $f$ which takes a polynomial from the vector space of polynomials of degree $n \le 2$ and then transforms them into another polynomial in the same vector space.

I've got two bases for this vector space, $A = (a_1...a_3)$ and B = $(b_1 ... b_3)$ and  $f$ has the same effect on the elements of this vector space, so $f(a_i) = f(b_i)$. Furthermore, since $f(a_i)$ is an element of the same vector space, they can be expressed as a linear combination of the elements of either $A$ or $B$... but the coefficients involved in these linear combinations are the same regardless of which basis I choose.

Why does above happen? What "causes" it? Was it the fact that the transformations of the elements of the bases are equal, or was it something else? Also, the "matrix representation" of $f$ in terms of either bases.... is exactly the same. Is this to be expected, and what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your claim, if I understand it correctly, is as follows:

> Let $a_1,a_2,a_3$ and $b_1,b_2,b_3$ be two bases for $\Bbb R^3$. Suppose that $f$ is a linear transformation such that $f(a_i) = f(b_i)$ for all $i$.
>
> Then, for all $i$: if $f(a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^3c_i a_i$ for $c_i \in \Bbb R$, then the same coefficients $c_i$ also satisfy $f(a_i) = \sum_{i=1}^3c_i b_i$.

This claim is false.  Consider the transformation given by the matrix
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0}
$$
(as a polynomial transformation, you can think of this as $f(ax^2 + bx + c) = a$).
Let $A$ be the standard basis, and take
$$
b_1 = (1,1,0), \quad b_2 = (1,-1,0), \quad b_3 = (0,0,1)
$$
Verify that $T(a_i) = T(b_i)$. However, 
$$
T(a_3) = a_1 = \frac 12 b_1 + \frac 12 b_2 \neq b_1
$$
so that "the coefficients involved in these linear combinations" are not the same.